# How do I integrate a logical boolean constraint into the standard matrix form of a Mixed Integer Linear Problem in scipy.optimize.milp / linprog?

Tags: python, linear-programming, boolean-logic, mixed-integer-programming, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to implement boolean logic and dependent variables into a Mixed-Integer Linear Program with [scipy.optimize.milp](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html) using a highs solver.

How do I set the actual matrices and vectors c, A_ub, b_ub, A_eq, b_eq to fit these exemplary Boolean operations of the exemplary MILP:

Boolean variables: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l

Minimize 1a+1b+...+1l

such that:

a OR b

c AND d

e XOR f

g NAND h

i != j

k == l

a,b,...,l are set to integers via the integrality parameter:

`integrality=np.repeat(3, 12+amount_of_helper_variables`)

And the lower and upper bounds are set to match boolean values 1 or 0 only:

Forall x in {a,b,...,l}: 0 <= x <= 1

I figured [this CS post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp) might help a lot as a general building guide, especially for solvers taking arbitrary formula input formats, but didn't get far myself with the conversion to standard matrix form until now.

I'm asking for a generalizable approach for conversion that basically can be used as a helper method for array creation and doesn't just apply to the stated problem but all boolean formula conversions for standard matrix form MILP using `np.array`s to juggle the variables and helpers around.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this in two steps:

1. Write things down equation based
2. Convert (painfully) into matrix format

So we have:

1. `x OR y`. I.e. `x=1 OR y=1`. That is `x+y>=1`.
2. `x AND y`. I.e. `x=1 AND y=1`. That means just fixing both variables to 1.
3. `x XOR y`. I.e. `x=1 XOR y=1`. That is `x+y=1`.
4. `x NAND y`. I.e. `not (x=1 AND y=1)`. So `x+y<=1`.
5. `x <> y`. This different notation for `x XOR y`. We handled that already.
6. `x=y`.This equation is ready as is. Maybe write as `x-y=0`.

Step 2, can usually be done in block format using a (large) piece of paper. Each column is a variable (or block of variables) and each row is a constraint. Here all matrix entries (coefficients) are 0, -1 or 1. E.g. `x-y=0` means: create a row with a coefficient of 1 in the x column and a -1 in the y column. See: [How to implement Linear Programming problem in scipy with complex objective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105156/how-to-implement-linear-programming-problem-in-scipy-with-complex-objective/74114827#74114827) for an example. It is often better to automate this and let a program do this for you. Python tools that do this for you are e.g. PuLP and Pyomo.

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer

Generalization is fine, but sometimes we lose exploitable substructures in mathematical-optimization. Sometimes this is bad!

#### Recommendation

That being said, i recommend the following.

##### Intermediate language: [Conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

- It's well known, that we can express any boolean function with it
- It's the form a [SAT-solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_solver) would expect: [DIMACS CNF](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/cnf/cnf.html) -> some empirical proof that it's a good pick
- There is lots of well-understood tooling
- There is a natural MILP-formulation

##### Transformation: CNF -> MILP

Helper-function

- **Input**: CNF defined on boolean variables (integral and bounded by `[0, 1]`)
- **Output**:

  - Set of constraints aka rows in constraint matrix `A_ub`
  - Set of constants aka scalars in `b_ub`

No matter what kind of input you have:

You might go through one joint CNF or decompose into many CNFs. And by definition you can concatenate them and their "conjunction." Meaning: `A_ub` and `b_ub` are stacking those outputs.

The transformation is simple:

```
for each c in cnf:
    for each disjunction in c:
        add constraint:
        ---------------
        sum of positive literals - sum of negative literals >= 1 - |negative literals|
```

Wiki: [Literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)):

```
A positive literal is just an atom (e.g. x).
A negative literal is the negation of an atom (e.g. not x).
```

Example for a given clause = disjunction in some cnf:

```
x1 or x2 or !x3
->
x1 + x2 + (1-x3) >= 1      easier to understand
<->
x1 + x2 - x3 >= 1 - 1      as proposed above
<->
x1 + x2 - x3 >= 0
```

(i left one step open -> we need to multiply our constraints with -1 to follow scipys standard-form; but well... you get the idea)

#### Tooling

##### CNF

- [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) has a boolean algebra module which could help (e.g. transform to cnf)
- [pyeda](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can achieve similar things (and is actually more targeting use-cases like that)

#### Remarks

There is tons of other potentiall relevant stuff, especially around CNF-creation.

These things are often important in the real-world, e.g. [Tseitin-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation) (for cases where a native cnf-creation would result in exponential-size). pyeda also knows about tseitin if i remember correctly.

But well... it's just a Stack-Overflow answer ;-)

#### References

If you need some reading material, i recommend:

> [Hooker, John N. Integrated methods for optimization. Vol. 170. New York: Springer, 2012.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-1900-6)